# Как извлечь число из колонки в таблице

Tags: python, файлы, анализ-данных, таблицы

Задание звучит так: в файле (pr1.txt) лежит таблица (данные):

| 10 | 10000 | 12.3 | 5403 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 20000 | 13 | 5000 |
| 30 | 30000 | 12.3 | 4312 |
| 250 | 250000 | 12.3 | 5123 |

Необходимо проанализировать вторую колонку и сравнить со значением p (вводится с клавиатуры) и вывести строчки, у которых вторая цифра меньше значения "p", записав их в файл

**Проблема** именно с тем как извлечь именно вторую колонку и сравнить с числом p

Для всех интересующихся кодом:

```
    print('Кондиционер|Номин воздух|Сопр|Масса|') #для задания
f=open('pr1.txt','r') #открываю файл для прочтения данных
while True:
    line=f.readline()
    if len(line) == 0:
        break
    print ('КД-',line,end='') #вывожу все данные в виде таблицы (требование задания)
f.close()
p=int(input('Введите сравниваемое значение : ')) #ввожу значение p
with open("pr1.txt") as group673:
    digits = re.findall(r'[-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?', group673.read()) #сделал лист, который выводит все числа, хотя думаю тут как раз не стоило это делать
    if (digits<p): #попытался сравнивать элемент списка с р, но словил ошибку :(
        minimal=digits
        print (minimal)
    print(digits)
```

Comment: Ну вот вы приведите свой код. как вы файл открываете, как читаете из него данные, как получаете пользовательской значение. в противном случае кажется, что вы просите нас сделать за вас задание. а здесь так не принято.

Comment: выписал код и пытался более понятно объяснить что я там делал. Прошу прощения за такой треш, пытаюсь учить питон, а задания из методички как будто для гениев программирования. Чтобы вы понимали это третья лабораторная, в первых двух было находждение площади круга и работа с текстом (удалить все русские буквы). Они дались на легке и всё было предельно ясно. Однако третья лаба и какой-то сложняк начался :(

Comment: Как выглядят данные в файле? Если они разделены определённым знаком, то проще их через `split()` в питоне на колонки разделить.

Comment: в файле они написаны через пробел, сейчас прочитаю как пользоваться split(), спасибо

Comment: Так то если ваша регулярка работает, то в `digits` у вас просто список строк, вторая колонка это `digits[1]`, ну и нужно строку в `int` перевести: `if int(digits[1])<p:` Но на будущее `split` всё-равно изучите, не всегда нужны регулярки уж прямо, можно гораздо проще всё делать.

Comment: @CrazyElf это повтор вопроса и в прошлый раз, тоже его задавали от женского имени

Comment: @CrazyElf `#попытался сравнивать элемент списка` - это явно не она писала, либо она не она

Comment: хотя ладно, я не осуждаю, пусть будет @Rozzi

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понял поставленную задачу, то Вы можете использовать для ее решения классические `pandas` и `numpy`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
p = float(input())
data = data[data[1] < p]

np.savetxt('answer.txt', data.values, fmt='%d')
```